# Enemy movement spinning should be attacking the playership but not do so?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**BasicEnemy**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BasicEnemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float speed = 3f;
    public float attack1Range = 1f;
    public int attack1Damage = 1;
    public float timeBetweenAttacks;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Rest();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void MoveToPlayer()
    {
        //rotate to look at player
        transform.LookAt(target.position);
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, -90, 0), Space.Self);

        //move towards player
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position) > attack1Range)
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0,     0));
        }
    }

    public void Rest()
    {

    }
}
```

**EnemyTerritory**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class EnemyTerritory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public BoxCollider territory;
    GameObject player;
    bool playerInTerritory;

    public GameObject enemy;
    BasicEnemy basicenemy;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        basicenemy = enemy.GetComponent<BasicEnemy>();
        playerInTerritory = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (playerInTerritory)
        {
            basicenemy.MoveToPlayer();
        }

        if (playerInTerritory)
        {
            basicenemy.Rest();
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject == player)
        {
            playerInTerritory = true;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject == player)
        {
            playerInTerritory = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Any feedback is welcome I trying to get enemies I added to the game to move toward the playership as if to attach and follow once I can get this done with the movement I will get them to shoot at the playership. right now all the new enemies I added are spinning really fast in circles. I get no syntax errors.

Comment: I think it is something about the `LookAt`, `Rotate` and `Translate` combination ... maybe you should checkout [Vector3.MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html)

Comment: I guess that is happening because of your
transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, -90, 0), Space.Self);
why do you need that?

Comment: I don't need the enemies I added spinning the way they are now If I change the values of the transform. Rotate will this help me get them to move towards the playership?

Comment: I'm going to go with the timeline for movement. Thank you, Everyone. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's definitely something fishy in the Update function because you're assigning (`=`) instead of checking for equality (`==`) in the condition.

Didn't you mean `playerInTerritory == true`?

```
void Update()
{
    if (playerInTerritory)
    {
        basicenemy.MoveToPlayer();
    } 
    else 
    {        
        basicenemy.Rest();
    }
}
```

If that doesn't help, add some `Debug.Log` statements in the trigger enter/exit functions to see when they are being called.

---

### Edit

Alright, I looked into the spinning. If you want the enemy to follow the player until it's within the attack range, you have both the wrong rotation and the wrong translation.

#### Rotation

```
// Rotate to look at player
transform.LookAt(target.position);
transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, -90, 0), Space.Self);
```

What this does, it makes the enemy turn towards the player (which you want) and the second line makes the enemy spin (90° anticlockwise each frame). If you don't want the enemy to spin, you don't need the line.
Just keep the 'Look At' function.

#### Translation

The translation problem is that you move in the direction of the **X** axis – which is not the direction of the player. You should calculate the direction vector first and translate along it.

The gist of it is always:

```
// normalized, so the vector affects only direction, not speed
Vector3 direction = (FROM.position - TO.position).normalized;
```

So, there:

```
Vector3 enemyToTargetDirection = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
enemyToTargetDirection.y = 0; // stay in the same height
transform.Translate(enemyToTargetDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

---

You could do it like this, but I think it looks better when the enemy rotates towards you gradually, instead of just 'snapping' in your direction.
In that case, the resulting function would look like this:

```
public void MoveToPlayer()
{
    Vector3 upwardsAxis = Vector3.up;

    float distanceToPlayer = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position);
    if (distanceToPlayer > attack1Range)
    {
        float step = Time.deltaTime * speed;
        Vector3 lookDirection = target.position - transform.position;
        if (lookDirection != Vector3.zero) // Prevents rotation errors
        {
            // Rotate over time
            Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookDirection, upwardsAxis);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookRotation, step * 2);
        }
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
    }
}
```

Oh, and by the way, for movement/rotation/physics in general, you should be using `FixedUpdate()` instead of the regular `Update()` (it makes the movement more fluent) and don't keep 'Awake', 'Start', 'Update' methods around if they are blank, since it can affect performance (slightly).

Comment: Thank you for responding I will look into this.

Comment: Hi, Rallix I made the changes above the enemies I added stop spinning and stay in the place where I place them what values should I set the transform to rotate or are those good values?

Comment: Hi; I tested out your code and tried making some fixes (see in the answer if it helps).

Comment: Hi, Rallix I going a different way I going to us my timeline to get player movement stuck with another issue though I will post in a moment.